# Is it possible to make SQL Server convert entries columns in a set of results

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I have the following setup...

```
Table: properties
p_id [pk]
p_propname
o_id_owners [fk]

Table: owners
o_id [pk]
o_extcode
o_fname
o_lname

Table: selectedfeatures
s_id [pk]
d_id_features [fk]
p_id_properties [fk]

Table: features
d_id [pk]
d_code
d_featurename
g_id_featuregroup [fk]

Table: featuregroup
g_id [pk]
g_featuregroupname
```

---

Ideally I want it to output

```
<header> Owner name | Owner Extcode | Prop name | [GROUP NAMES (featuregroup)] 
<row> Owner name | Owner Extcode | Prop name | ^feature code | ^feature code |
```

Its the group names bit I'm struggling with; The tables are linked and I can get the records to display thus:

```
<header> Owner name | Owner Extcode | Prop name | Feature Name
<row> Owner name | Owner Extcode | Prop name | Feature Name
<row> Owner name | Owner Extcode | Prop name | Feature Name
```

Comment: don't use the <pre>..</pre> codes - they don't work too well. Highlight your lines that need to be formatted, and then click on the "code" button (010 101) on the editor toolbar, or press Ctrl-K - you'll get **much** better results!

Comment: @Chris: You need to provide what the fk is relating to - it's not clear what relates to what.

Comment: @marc thanks;
@OMG g_id_featuregroup for instance is Tbl: featuregroup; PK: g_id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you seen this?  [Five methods converting rows to columns](http://sqlserveradvisor.blogspot.com/2009/03/sql-server-convert-rows-to-columns.html)

Comment: Good link; I was drowning in reference sites. Ta